# What is the use case of the SPEED_LIMITS_VAR layer in the PDE?

Tags: here-api

I am using the https://m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json method to match a GPX trace and get the speed limit data for LINK_IDs throughout the route.

The documents for the PDE layers state:

*Please be aware that 3-4 different layers need to be evaluated to determine the actual link speed limit: SPEED_LIMITS_FCx (general speed limits), SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FCx (variable speed limits), SPEED_LIMITS_COND_FCx (conditional speed limits), and TRUCK_SPEED_LIMITS_FCx (in case of a vehicle is a truck). The lowest speed limit on a link is the legal one.*

I ideally want to know how the speed limit varies on roads with variable speed signs/smart motorways where the traffic determines the speed.

The information I receive from the layer is:

```
{
"CONDITION_ID": "743194725",
"LINK_ID": "811864174",
"VSS_ID": "100384",
"DIRECTION": "2",
}
```

As it doesn't provide a speed limit value, how would I use this information, and is it of any use for what I need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The use case of SPEED_LIMITS_VAR layer is to recognize that on some road link a speed limit could be volatility time by time and it means that you can get reality *speed limit only by currently traffic info*. [You know, the SPEED_LIMITS_VAR layer also gives some information about DIRECTION, VARIABLE_SPEED_SIGN_LOCATION, TIME_OVERRIDE, VEHICLE_TYPES, DATE_TIMES.](https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=latest&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC1)

To get traffic info you can utilize TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FCn layer, currently you can send the request to API like this: https://pde.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=car&departure=2020-11-23T13:54:14&attributes=SPEED_LIMITS_FCn(*),TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FCn(*)&app_id=---&app_code=---&routeMatch=1 but unfortunately, currently, you have to use only domain name "pde.api.here.com" in request and use for it only app_id, app_code parameters. For domain names like https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com and apiKey credentials the layer TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FCn (as 'attributes' parameter) will be available later.

The description of layer TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FCn you can read on https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=TSRWORLD&release=&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FC1

If you don't have app_id, app_code but have apiKey then to get info from layer TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FC you need to send second request using https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com and [Corridor search](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-search-corridor.html) or [Tiles search](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/resource-tiles.html)